# Store Report Data in a SQL table

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a report that is ran every quarter. The report is based on current values and creates a score card. We do this for about 50 locations and then have to manually create a report to compare the previous run to the current run. I'd like to automate by taking the report data and saving it to a table for each location and each quarter, then we can run reports that will show the data changes over time.

Data Sample:
Employees Active
Employees with ref checks
Clients Active
Clients with careplans

The reports are fairly complex and pulling data from many different tables so creating this via a query may not work or be just as complex. Any ideas on how to get the report data to a table without having to export each to a CSV or Excel file then importing manually?

Comment: Using a SSRS report to generate archive data is not a good strategy. You're embedding existing complexity and mystery code into your process. If you already have reports whose business rules are too complex to migrate into a database, that's a red flag.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm just looking for some ways to automate a few things. It's not that the business rules are too complex, it's just the report is a high level view of multiple KPIs and very useful when ran. We find it even more useful to compare over time so thought making a table of the data would provide some opportunities to see trend lines over time and across multiple business units.

Comment: You could get really creative and use something like beautiful soup to scrape rendered html. I think you’ll need to render it regardless. I’m not aware of a way to get to pre rendered data and even if you could, that starts you down the path of processing data in which you should just go straight to the source.

Answer (score 0):

If each score card has some dimensions (or metric names) and aggregate values (or metric values) then you can just add a time series table with columns for:

- date
- location or business unit
- or instead of date and location, a scorecard ID (linking to another table with scorecard metadata)
- dimension grouping
- scores/values/metrics

Then, assuming you're creating the reports with a stored procedure, you can add a flag parameter to the stored procedure to update this table while generating a specific report on a date. This might be less work and/or faster than importing from CSVs, if you store intermediate report data into a temporary table that you can select from when additionally storing the data into the time series table described above.